# dav2fs caching problem on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, cache, webdav

I have `apache`/`mod_dav` and `davfs2` all on the same host. `davfs2` is used to mount what Apache is serving to the local filesystem - a sort of loopback. The purpose is that the content of the files served is dynamic and comes from a postgres database via php. In this case the file is an email footer/disclaimer that changes periodically and is read by the mail program.

This mostly works well, but when I try to `cp` a file from the dav directory to another part of the filesystem, it `cp` does not seem to trigger the 'has the file changed' check in davfs2 - it just gets the cached copy. Note the php file has not changed, only the dynamic content because something has been updated in the database.

On the other hand, if I `cp` again 5 seconds later, the correct file contents is copied. I've ended up with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /root/pgdav/disclaimer.html /etc/postfix/disclaimer.html
sleep 5
cp /root/pgdav/disclaimer.html /etc/postfix/disclaimer.html
```

Caching related headers in php are set as follows:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

I've set `file_refresh    0` in `davfs2.conf`.

My question is: Is there some other setting I am missing to correct this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from the davfs2 mailing lists and thought I'd share it here:

> [On open davfs2 will send a conditional GET request, which depends on correct Etag values.](https://savannah.nongnu.org/support/index.php?107933)

Once I made sure I was serving up ETag headers the problem went away.